# How to get a string variable with the ID field from the database MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I have a database and MSSQL code in vbscript:

```vb
Dim conn, SQL, rs
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=DJ-PC;Initial Catalog=Baza_NC;user id ='user_baza_nc';password='Password1'"
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn

myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "' WHERE Klienci_NC.ID = '" & ID_zmienna & "'"

myCommand.Execute
myConn.Close
```

[image]

When I use the ID with the participation of a txt file as a counter to work well.
The problem appeared when I wanted to use the MSSQL database autoincremant.

I need a string variable to the variable & ID_zmienna &
How to get a string variable with the ID field from the database?

Comment: So you go through the trouble of using `ADODB.Command` only to undo all your hard work by concatenating variables directly into the string leaving you open to SQL Injection.

Comment: cast(ID_zmienna as nvarchar(10)) ... ID_zmienna.ToString()?

Comment: @Veljko89 This isn't .Net there is no `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying to call an `INT` data type in SQL as a `VARCHAR`.

The query should be

```vb
myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "' WHERE Klienci_NC.ID = " & ID_zmienna
```

you only pass `'` for string data types in SQL Server, integers are just

```
[column] = int_value
```

Having said all that you should be passing the parameters in the `.Parameters` collection of the `ADODB.Command` object rather than specifying them directly in the SQL query string. As it stands the page is open to [SQL Injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and also means you have to handle not passing `'` when dealing with `INT` and escaping extra `'` in strings etc., which just isn't necessary.

```vb
Dim SQL, myCommand
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=DJ-PC;Initial Catalog=Baza_NC;user id=user_baza_nc;password=Password1"

'Most ADO providers expect a `?` to denote where a parameter is expected.
SQL = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = ? WHERE Klienci_NC.ID = ?"

Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
With myCommand
  'No need for ADODB.Connection object ADODB.Command can create one from the
  'Connection String.
  .ActiveConnection = DB_CONNECT_STRING
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = SQL
  'Define parameters in order they appear in the query.
  Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@klient", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))
  Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@id", adInteger, adParamInput, 4))
  'Only running an update statement so no need to return a
  'ADODB.Recordset.
  Call .Execute(, Array(Klient_niceform, ID_zmienna), adExecuteNoRecords)
End With
'Release the object from memory
Set myCommand = Nothing
```

---

#### Useful Links

Assuming you are using Classic ASP with VBScript

- [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417073339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml) *(if you are having problems with the ADO constants like `adCmdText`, `adInteger` etc., being undefined this will help)*

Otherwise you will need to define the ADO constants yourself like so;

```vb
Const adCmdText = 1
Const adInteger = 3
Const adVarWChar = 202
Const adParamInput = 1
Const adExecuteNoRecords = &H00000080
```